# Kubernetes is sending traffic to unhealthy pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, readinessprobe

I have some setup of 2 pods using StatefulSet behind a `nodeport` service with AWS ingress and sending traffic to this service through ALB endpoint. Then I patch the StatefulSet to have only 1 pod. I have configured this StatefulSet with readiness probe and lifecycle policy like this to avoid getting traffic on unhealthy pod.

Liveness and Readiness Probe:

```yaml
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:80/health); if [ \"$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi; cat /tmp/.health-check"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:80/health); if [ \"$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi; cat /tmp/.health-check"]
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 2
```

Lifecycle Policy:

```
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/touch", "/tmp/.health-check"]
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["sh", "-c", "rm -r /tmp/.health-check; sleep 60"]
```

terminationGracePeriodSeconds

```yaml
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

But when I patch StatefulSet to have only pod, one get into Terminating state and it became unhealthy but it still receives the traffic. How to debug this issue.

Some timestamps and actions:

Patched STS: Sun Jun 25 16:23:28 UTC 2023

Pod became unhealthy (checked using `kubectl get pods` and observed 0/1 in status): Sun Jun 25 16:23:47 UTC 2023

Last request received on Pod-2 (checked on kibana): Sun Jun 25 16:24:38 UTC 2023

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming

Answer (score 0):

This isn't desired behavior, when a pod goes to terminating state, the traffic isn't sent to it. You should get the `Endpoints` to be sure whether it is an active endpoint or not. Run

```
kubectl get endpoints SERVICE_NAME
```

or can run continuously

```
watch kubectl get endpoints SERVICE_NAME
```

the SERVICE_NAME should be the name of the K8s service that you created. Confirm if the unhealthy pod ip address is there or not.

Comment: I've already checked this and as soon as pod gets into terminating state, it's IP is removed from endpoints. Is there any other thing I can check

Comment: if thats the case, then traffic will not be sending to that pod, how have you checked that traffic is sending to that pod?

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, we have setup ELK and I've verified that pod logs from Kibana